# SceneKit objects not showing up in ARSCNView about 1 out of 100 times

Tags: augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I can't share much code because it's proprietary, but this is a bug that's been haunting me for awhile. We have SceneKit geometry added to the ARKit face node and displayed inside an ARSCNView. It works perfectly almost all of the time, but about 1 in 100 times, nothing shows up at all. The ARSession is running, and none of the parent nodes are set to hidden. Further, when I look at Debug Memory Graph function in Xcode, the geometry *appears* to be entirely visible there (and doesn't seem to be set to hidden). **I can see all the nodes attached to the face node perfectly within the ARSCNView of the memory graph, but on the screen, nothing shows up.** This has been an issue for multiple iOS versions, so it didn't just appear with a recent update.

Has anybody run into a similar problem, or does anybody have any ideas to look into? Is it an apple bug, or is there a timing issue I might not be aware of? It's been really hard to debug because of how infrequent it is, and I haven't found it discussed on any other forums (but point me in the right direction if there is a previous discussion). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***This is pretty common practice if AR tracking is poor for some reason***.

I ran into a similar problem too. I think it's definitely a tracking error which arises due to the fault of the user of AR app. Sometimes, if you're using World Tracking Config in ARKit and track a surrounding environment offhandedly or if you are tracking under inappropriate conditions – you get a sloppy tracking data which results in situation when your World Grid/Axis may be unpredictably shifted aside and your model may fly away somewhere. If such a situation arises - look for your model somewhere nearby – maybe it’s behind you.

If you're using a gadget with a LiDAR, the aforementioned situation is almost impossible, but if you're using a gadget with no LiDAR you need thoroughly track your room. Also there must be good lighting conditions and high-contrast real-world objects with distinguishable non-repetitive textures.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, since it either happens or it doesn't on certain runs of the app, regardless of the conditions, when the reported tracking state by the AR configuration is reporting full tracking. FWIW I'm using ARFaceTrackingConfiguration, and the front-facing iPhone camera.